# List all websites in IIS c#

Tags: c#, iis

Is there a way to list all active websites that exist within IIS using c#?

Thanks

Sp

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an [article](http://cstruter.com/blog/306) explaining how this could be done using classes from the [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace as well as the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613523.aspx) namespace which was introduced with IIS 7.

Answer (score 30):

For IIS 7 you can use Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv) and the following code

```
        var iisManager = new ServerManager();
        SiteCollection sites = iisManager.Sites;
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! However, it should be noted that the executing application (VS or the app itself) will need elevated permissions to run this (at least on my Windows 7 setup).

Comment: This was the best thing I found on the internet in a long time(work related of course!)

Answer (score -9):

If anyone is intrested i used the following

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
sizeInBytes = (from file in files let fileInfo = new FileInfo(file) select fileInfo.Length).Sum();
```

Comment: This snippet assumes that directories within the specified directory represents actual websites, which isn't necessarily true.

My guess is that you're actually trying to list virtual folders within a site?

Rather use the classes within the System.DirectoryServices, it will be more accurate.