# IIS - Query for Web Sites

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I'm working on an application which should add a vdir on the default web site.
Before adding the vdir I need to check whether the default web site exists.
The way I'm doing it today is using the DirectoryServices via c# ([example](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/cs_enum_iis_websites.htm)).

The problem is that using the DirectoryServices on IIS7 is possible only when the IIS6 backwards compatibility roles are installed.
I have no problem with creating the vdir since it is done after adding the IIS6 b/w compatibility roles (yes, the default web site test must be before :-) ).

Is there any alternative way for querying the IIS?
Maybe through the registry/file system?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4593412/114029

Comment: Leniel: Thanks but the answers in the post does not solve the problem. One of them is using the DirectoryServices as I do and the second one is trying to use the FileSystem but it doesn't really work in all cases.