# How to get list of working sites in IIS exspress?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, localhost, iis-express

In our wpf application we host the silverlight application to iisexpress , hosting working fine . But when we close the wpf application we don't stop the silverlight application.  second time we start wpf application the silverlight application once again hosted in iisexpress as new website .  
         Is any option to check is silverlight app still on iisexpress and if exits reopen the previously hosted silverlight application .

i tried some links like [List all websites in IIS c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593412/list-all-websites-in-iis-c-sharp) It giving some permission error .
[Starting and stopping IIS Express programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772092/starting-and-stopping-iis-express-programmatically)  it also not working and the solution need Process ID of the application .In my case i cannot get that .  
we are using windows 8 , vs2012 and iisexpress 8(default)   
with regards
 jophy

Comment: I don't really get it. I understand your problem, but how are you hosting the silverlight app? Via a webbrowser control I assume?

Comment: i adding hosting code : private static Process StartProcess(string filePath, string arguments)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe", arguments);
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            return Process.Start(info);
        }