# Iterate over SiteCollection

Tags: c#, iis

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884444/9875263) and I need to iterate over it and to get the names of all iis websites, how to iterate over it?

I need something like:

```
        ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
        SiteCollection sites = iisManager.Sites;

        foreach (string s in sites)
        {
         // tried to get all the sites names
        }
```

Comment: what does "sites" store in it. Instead of a string based iterator, use a dynamic 'var' so that you don't need to provide the type and can view its contents to chose the correct property to consume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read about **[foreach loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)** and **[`SideCollection` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.sitecollection(v=vs.90).aspx)**:

```
foreach (var site in sites)
{
    //use site.Name for site names
}
```

Or

```
foreach (Site site in sites)
{
    //use site.Name for site names
}
```

`SiteCollection` stores **[`Site`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.site(v=vs.90).aspx)** objects, which have `Name` property.

References: **[foreach loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)**, **[SideCollection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.sitecollection(v=vs.90).aspx)**, **[Site class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.site(v=vs.90).aspx)**